# Can we list own token in coinbace test net : https://public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/

Tags: token, coinbase-api

Hi I am creating a cryto wallet application, which can be later connected to COINBASE exchange. So in order to test API integration, i used https://public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/    API ..   and it's working fine.  Now I need to add one of my tokens in Ethereum test network into  "sandbox.pro .coinbase".  Can anyone tell me, how can I list it in the coinbase test exchange... Thanks in advance

Not found any option in coinbase test net. Only 8 test tokens are available for trade